# Could not load type 'Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage

Tags: dll, sitecore, sitecore8.2, login-page

I'm trying to get a website working locally that was recently migrated from Sitecore 6.5 to 8.2. I've updated all the dll references, but on trying to access /sitecore I'm getting the error

```
Could not load type 'Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage'
```

I assume I am missing a reference, though I'm not sure what assembly that is in.

Comment: `Sitecore.Client.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, I would recommend running a full comparison against the fileset of a default 8.2 instance. When doing an upgrade, after the upgrade you may have deployed a customized login page or something similar which has the wrong references in the markup.

By comparing your installation against a clean 8.2 installation you can look for files outside of the bin folder that are incorrect and don't have the right markup. In this case, that might be missing DLLs in the bin folder, or an override of the default login ASPX page.